# Erro updating uniquewith-validator to Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I already used the validator in Laravel 4.2, I'm starting to upgrade to L5.2, did the installation as the documentation ran the 'update composer', and checked that the folder was created on vendors, but when adding the service provider

```
Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider
```

and run composer update again, the following error occurs:

> [ReflectionException] Class validator does not exist

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

I also tried adding the service provider as follows:

```
Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider::class
```

But the error remains.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hello, has no code, I got this error on a clean install of Laravel, I managed to contact the felixkiss and he confirmed that the error occurs by changes in account laravel 5.2 validation mechanism, he already released the fix, just upgrade to the 2.0.7 version, I still have to do some more tests apparently everything is working. Thank you.

Repository: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator
issue: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator/issues/54